# Morphism bewteen normal schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume that $\psi: X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism between two irreducible normal schemes. And $\psi$ maps the generic point of $X$ to the generic of $Y$.

Then can we prove that $\psi_* \mathscr{O}_X$ is a locally free $\mathscr{O}_Y$-module with rank $[k(X):k(Y)]$.

Answer (score 0):

Please try $k[x^2,xy,y^2]\subset k[x,y]$.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question so many times. What about the case when X, Y are 1-dimensional?

Comment: @IntoksLiobein Try $\mathbb{A}^1\subset\mathbb{P}^1$.